# Does probiotics bacteria from yogurt live in the mouth too? Does it populate the mouth/throat or just the gut?

Tags: bacteriology

Yes I was basically just wondered this as I've taken probiotics in a pill form but those only go to the gut. I guessed the mouth needs probiotics too and I wondered if yogurt can accomplish that.

I also found conflicting stuff on the internet: some say enzymes in the mouth kill the bacteria in yogurt, others say yogurt helps bad breath for example which means it does have beneficial bacteria that live there in the mouth probably.

Answer (score 3):

of course they do... the question is for how long.
Probiotics will tend only to affect the microbiome in the digestive tract for a while.  For yogurt supplemented with probiotics subjects microbiomes drifted back [within 48 hours](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-28491-x).  Depending on your diet the individuals can hang out for a while or persist.  Children, who tend to drink more dairy have a more persistent *Lactobacillus* signature.